# Different results from VSCode built-in terminal and regular terminal (raspbian)

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code, terminal, raspbian

I have been making a little project in Python all the time executing it form the VSCode terminal.
Right now, I am trying to schedule its execution from the crontab file (so I have to use the "regular" terminal).
The code itself is the following:

```
data = openMainJSON("itemsToLookFor")
for x in data["items"]:
    scraping(x.get("name"),x.get("minPrice"),x.get("distance"))
```

The function openMainJSON simply gets a JSON file and loads it as a dictionary

```
def openMainJSON(filename):
try:
    fullname = filename + ".JSON"
    file = open(fullname)
    data = json.load(file)
    return data
except:
    return "error"
```

In the VSCode terminal it loads with no problems, but in the built-in raspberry terminal... I get the following message

```
    for x in data["items"]:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Which makes sense if we are talking about a String, but data is a dictionary

Thank you very much for the help in advance

Comment: Check what data is, but Python doesn't lie: contrary to what you think, it *is* a string.

Comment: You need to provide enough information from anyone else to reproduce your issue. Which terminal? Which vscode version? Python version? Command to run? Input files? OS?

Comment: The issue is that `openMainJSON` returns `"error"`, but you don't handle the case. Bare `except:` is a bad idea: `except:` catches all possible errors, including ones you didn't anticipate. Remove the `try-except` block and run the code again - you should see a different error.

Comment: As mentioned above, I think you can try using exception statements. Please also provide a reproducible case. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the error was related to the return value of the function openMainJSON, it returned "error" (as a String) instead of the dictionary

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).